# CodeIgniter - Accessing multi-dimentional array

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

So I have problem in accessing value in multidimentional array. Here's print_r result/array structure of my $klasemen->data:

> ```
> Array (
> [0] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [team] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 5055
>                 [name] => Manchester United
>             )
>
>         [breadcrumb] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => stdClass Object
>                     (
>                         [id] => 1
>                         [name] => Bola
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => stdClass Object
>                     (
>                         [id] => 2
>                         [name] => Internasional
>                     )
>
>                 [2] => stdClass Object
>                     (
>                         [id] => 23
>                         [name] => Liga Premiere
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [games_played] => 23
>         [wins] => 18
>         [draws] => 2
>         [losses] => 3
>         [goals_scored] => 57
>         [goals_against] => 30
>         [goals_difference] => 27
>         [points] => 56
>     )
>
> [1] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [team] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [id] => 5057
>                 [name] => Manchester City
>             )
>
>         [breadcrumb] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => stdClass Object
>                     (
>                         [id] => 1
>                         [name] => Bola
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => stdClass Object
>                     (
>                         [id] => 2
>                         [name] => Internasional
>                     )
>
>                 [2] => stdClass Object
>                     (
>                         [id] => 23
>                         [name] => Liga Premiere
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [games_played] => 23
>         [wins] => 15
>         [draws] => 6
>         [losses] => 2
>         [goals_scored] => 45
>         [goals_against] => 19
>         [goals_difference] => 26
>         [points] => 51
>     )
> ```

I want to access the name of competition (eg. Liga Premiere) and print it on my view but I keep getting **"Message:  Trying to get property of non-object"**. I believe something's wrong with the syntax or my way accessing array in Breadcrumb array. I'm new and I get confused with this multidimentional array thing T_T

Here's the line code on my view when I want to print the value (I'm pretty sure something's wrong with it).

> echo $klasemen->data->breadcrumb[2]->name

Anyway $klasemen is variable that contains all data.
Anyone can help me with this? Thank you! :-)

Comment: $klasemen[1]->breadcrumb[2]->name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this paulfah

You

```
$klasemen->data->breadcrumb[2]->name
```

You just need to change $klasemen->data for $klasemen[1] as it is an array. The data property does not exist in your object.

Solution:

```
$klasemen[1]->breadcrumb[2]->name
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation on what changes you have done how it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad reference to `data`. Try this:

```
echo $klasemen[0]->breadcrumb[2]->name
```

Comment: Actually data is array inside $klasemen. Anyway thank you it really helps me understand how to access the inner array! My problem's solved. Thanks a lot! :-D

Answer (score 0):

The following code :

```
echo $klasemen->data->breadcrumb[2]->name
```

is equivalent to :

```
echo $klasemen[0]->breadcrumb[2]->name
```

You are currently dealing with array of objects. And you need to provide index to specify the current object item.